# Is there any way to return the element that does not pass a filter in stream?

Tags: java, filter, stream

I have a list of string elements and I want to apply a filter to divide the list into two sub list, elements that start with "el" and others.
is there any way to divide the list using just one filter?

```
List elements = List.of("e1", "el2", "el3", "4 el", "5 el")
```

example:

```
elements.stream()
        .filter(s -> s.startWith("el))
        .collect( /* something that hold both the element that pass the filter and element that does not */ )
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like so.

- use `groupingBy` and create a `Map<String, List<String>>`
- if the string starts with "el" group using the `els` key
- otherwise, use the `others` key

```
List<String> elements = List.of("e1", "el2", "el3", "4 el", "5 el");
Map<String, List<String>> map = elements.stream().collect(
        Collectors.groupingBy(str -> str.startsWith("el") ?
                "els" : "others"));

map.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

prints

```
els=[el2, el3]
others=[e1, 4 el, 5 el]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a threshold condition which determine if an item will go to group `A`, otherwise `B`, I suggest using `partitioningBy` for this.

For example:

```
    List<String> elements = List.of("e1", "el2", "el3", "4 el", "5 el");
    //create the partition map
    Map<Boolean,List<String>> partitionMap = elements.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(s-> s.startsWith("el")));

    //getting the partitions
    List<String> startsWithEl = partitionMap.get(true);
    List<String> notStartingWilEl = partitionMap.get(false);
```

Now each list will hold its partition .